# Save mongodb document in each for loop iteration, instead of waiting to for loop finish

Tags: mongodb, for-loop, mongoose

I want to create a new document in each iteration, not AS-IS, the documents are all stored after the for loop has finished all iterations. I have to wait on 58.000 items in the for loop, until it saves to the database...

Isn't it possible to tell mongoose somehow to save each document after each iteration on the for loop?

The mongoose schema I'm referring to in the code is called: `PartCluster`

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const fuzzball = require("fuzzball");
const CompanyPart = require("../../models/parts");
const PartCluster = require("../../models/PartClusters");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/autoMDM", {
  keepAlive: true,
  reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,
  useMongoClient: true
});

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connection.on("error", err => {
  console.error(`Mongoose connection error: ${err}`);
  process.exit(1);
});

CompanyPart.find({}, { partName: 1 }, (err, parts) => {
  var obj = {};
  for (var i = 0, len = parts.length; i < len; i++) {
    obj[parts[i]["partName"]] = parts[i];
  }
  parts = new Array();
  for (var key in obj) {
    parts.push(obj[key]);
  }
  createCluster(parts);
});

function createCluster(arrayOfParts) {
  let usedStrings = [];
  let clusterArray = [];
  len = arrayOfParts.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfParts.length; i++) {
    let cluster = [];
    y = 1;
    if (usedStrings.includes(arrayOfParts[i].partName)) {
      continue;
    }
    console.log(`item: ${i}, partName: ${arrayOfParts[i].partName}`);
    for (var j = y; j < arrayOfParts.length; j++) {
      if (
        fuzzball.token_sort_ratio(
          arrayOfParts[i].partName,
          arrayOfParts[j].partName
        ) > "70"
      ) {
        if (
          arrayOfParts[i].partName.toLowerCase() !==
            arrayOfParts[j].partName.toLowerCase() &&
          !cluster.includes(arrayOfParts[j].partName) &&
          !usedStrings.includes(arrayOfParts[j].partName)
        ) {
          cluster.push(arrayOfParts[j].partName);
          usedStrings.push(arrayOfParts[j].partName);
        }
      }
    }
    if (cluster.length > 0) {
      let obj = {};
      obj.clusterName = arrayOfParts[i].partName;
      obj.partCluster = cluster.sort();
      const query = { clusterName: arrayOfParts[i].partName };
      const update = obj;
      const options = { upsert: true };
      PartCluster.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log("Error when saving cluster: ", error);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

example docs from parts

```
const parts = [
    {"_id":"59a942a8c0b7467bf08711df","partName":"0"},
    {"_id":"59a94299c0b7467bf084a917","partName":"9129"},
    {"_id":"59a94299c0b7467bf084a918","partName":"9130"},
    {"_id":"59a94297c0b7467bf08455e0","partName":"9132"},
    {"_id":"59a94298c0b7467bf084701f","partName":"9176"},
    {"_id":"59a94298c0b7467bf084809f","partName":"9180"},
    {"_id":"59a94295c0b7467bf083edf3","partName":"9187"},
    {"_id":"59a94298c0b7467bf0848439","partName":"9190"},
    {"_id":"59a94295c0b7467bf083ed35","partName":"9227"},
    {"_id":"59a94295c0b7467bf083ed36","partName":"9235"},
    {"_id":"59a94298c0b7467bf0847032","partName":"9237"},
    {"_id":"59a94298c0b7467bf0848438","partName":"9257"},
    {"_id":"59a94298c0b7467bf0848c39","partName":"9279"},
    {"_id":"59a94295c0b7467bf083edae","partName":"9424"},
    {"_id":"59a94295c0b7467bf083edb3","partName":"9425"},
    {"_id":"59a9429ec0b7467bf08563ec","partName":"9430"},
    {"_id":"59a9429ec0b7467bf08563f6","partName":"9435"},
    {"_id":"59a94295c0b7467bf083edb9","partName":"9542"},
    {"_id":"59a94295c0b7467bf083edc4","partName":"9577"},
    {"_id":"59a942a9c0b7467bf0871bc0","partName":"2651513067"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf0874ba5","partName":"COVER"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf0874923","partName":"BRACKET"},
    {"_id":"59a942a7c0b7467bf086e714","partName":"RING-SNAP"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf087443e","partName":"RETAINER"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf08749d4","partName":"SPRING"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf08748c8","partName":"HOUSING"},
    {"_id":"59a942a7c0b7467bf086eaef","partName":"WAGNER PART"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf0874a4f","partName":"RING"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf0874aef","partName":"GEAR"},
    {"_id":"59a942a8c0b7467bf086f701","partName":"HEAD"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf08741f2","partName":"WIPER"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf08749ea","partName":"SEAL"},
    {"_id":"59a94293c0b7467bf08351d6","partName":"PISTON SYS"},
    {"_id":"59a942a7c0b7467bf086eac5","partName":"O-RING-VITON"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf08749cb","partName":"SHIM"},
    {"_id":"59a942a6c0b7467bf086aa6b","partName":"CAGE"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf0873e29","partName":"ROD"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf0874a30","partName":"ELEMENT"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf0874bb6","partName":"PLATE"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf087498e","partName":"DIAPHRAGM"},
    {"_id":"59a94293c0b7467bf08351e1","partName":"SUPPORT      -UPPER"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf0874a76","partName":"VALVE"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf0873fe5","partName":"LOCK"},
    {"_id":"59a94293c0b7467bf08351e7","partName":"FLANG-SPLIT"},
    {"_id":"59a942a9c0b7467bf0872e56","partName":"LOCKWASHER"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf087425c","partName":"CAPSCREW"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf0874b4d","partName":"HOSE"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf0874bc9","partName":"HOSE ASSEMBLY"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf0874b58","partName":"WASHER"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf0874b96","partName":"BEARING"},
    {"_id":"59a942a7c0b7467bf086e06d","partName":"DIODE ASSY"},
    {"_id":"59a94293c0b7467bf08351f0","partName":"BRUSH ASSY"},
    {"_id":"59a942a7c0b7467bf086e9b1","partName":"BOARD"},
    {"_id":"59a942a8c0b7467bf0870900","partName":"CABLE ASSY"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf0874ad6","partName":"NUT"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf0874af7","partName":"SCREW"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf0874aa4","partName":"BUSHING"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf0874ad7","partName":"STUD"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf0874b7c","partName":"BOLT"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf0874928","partName":"CYLINDER"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf08749ba","partName":"RETAINING RING"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf0874a39","partName":"CLAMP"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf08749dd","partName":"PLUG"},
    {"_id":"59a94293c0b7467bf0835208","partName":"SPR BOOSTER"},
    {"_id":"59a942a9c0b7467bf087325b","partName":"FLANGE SCREW"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf0874a75","partName":"O-RING"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf0874b51","partName":"CAP"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf0874945","partName":"BAFFLE PLATE"},
    {"_id":"59a9429ac0b7467bf084f061","partName":"CLAMP, HOSE"},
    {"_id":"59a942a9c0b7467bf0873a70","partName":"BOOT"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf0874b73","partName":"SWITCH"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf0874156","partName":"HOSE ASSY"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf0874b3b","partName":"PISTON"},
    {"_id":"59a942aac0b7467bf08740c0","partName":"ROTOR"}
]
```

docs saved in mongodb:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b5f107366901668ab00074"),
    "clusterName" : "9129",
    "__v" : 0,
    "partCluster" : [ 
        "9132", 
        "9190", 
        "9279"
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b5f107366901668ab00075"),
    "clusterName" : "9130",
    "__v" : 0,
    "partCluster" : [ 
        "9180", 
        "9430"
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b5f107366901668ab00078"),
    "clusterName" : "9176",
    "__v" : 0,
    "partCluster" : [ 
        "9187"
    ]
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b5f107366901668ab00079"),
    "clusterName" : "9227",
    "__v" : 0,
    "partCluster" : [ 
        "9237", 
        "9257"
    ]
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b5f107366901668ab0007d"),
    "clusterName" : "9424",
    "__v" : 0,
    "partCluster" : [ 
        "9542"
    ]
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b5f107366901668ab0007e"),
    "clusterName" : "SPRING",
    "__v" : 0,
    "partCluster" : [ 
        "RING"
    ]
}

/* 7 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b5f107366901668ab0007f"),
    "clusterName" : "HOUSING",
    "__v" : 0,
    "partCluster" : [ 
        "BUSHING"
    ]
}

/* 8 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b5f107366901668ab00083"),
    "clusterName" : "PISTON SYS",
    "__v" : 0,
    "partCluster" : [ 
        "PISTON"
    ]
}

/* 9 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b5f107366901668ab00084"),
    "clusterName" : "CAPSCREW",
    "__v" : 0,
    "partCluster" : [ 
        "SCREW"
    ]
}

/* 10 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b5f107366901668ab00086"),
    "clusterName" : "CLAMP",
    "__v" : 0,
    "partCluster" : [ 
        "CAP"
    ]
}

/* 11 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b5f107366901668ab00087"),
    "clusterName" : "LOCKWASHER",
    "__v" : 0,
    "partCluster" : [ 
        "WASHER"
    ]
}

/* 12 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b5f107366901668ab0008a"),
    "clusterName" : "BOLT",
    "__v" : 0,
    "partCluster" : [ 
        "BOOT"
    ]
}

/* 13 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b5f107366901668ab0008b"),
    "clusterName" : "HOSE ASSEMBLY",
    "__v" : 0,
    "partCluster" : [ 
        "HOSE ASSY"
    ]
}

/* 14 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b5f107366901668ab0008d"),
    "clusterName" : "9235",
    "__v" : 0,
    "partCluster" : [ 
        "9425", 
        "9435"
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is the point of the 5 iterations? The expected results are somewhat obscured, so if you could instead include a small source sample of data and the result expected from that sample it would be much clearer to guide you on better ways to obtain that result.

Comment: @NeilLunn  sorry, it should state arrayOfParts.length I have updated the question

Comment: You need a bit more explanation than that. I just touched on the obvious point that there is an "iteration of five times" which is done after you stuff the entire collection contents into an array ( first efficiency to improve ) and what is needed from you is to explain your current logic in order for it to be analysed for "improvement". Since that part does not depend on the length of results, it requires your explanation. As I said, the "clearest way to explain" is always by "demonstration". Show a source, and show the results from that source. If we can reproduce, then we can improve.

Comment: @NeilLunn, the for loop is Ok, that I need to know if how to  create a new document in the mongodb for each iteration in the first for loop. Example when first object is created and I pass it to the findOneAndUpdate method. The document is not saved in the mongodb.. only when I have looping all over the arrayOfParts.length (which is in my case approx 58.000 records). I would like to save the document directly and not have to wait on the for loop to complete. Is it possible?

Comment: Make your explanation in the question please. I'm asking you to show 5 to 10 source documents and from those documents show what the final created documents in the collection should look like. Don't make presumptions of what you think the solution is. To me there are clear things I think you should be doing instead, but to correct the algorithm I ( and others ) need to clearly see what you expect as a result. That is what you are being asked to do and how you ask a question of your peers here.

Comment: @NeilLunn, sorry. I just added example docs of "parts". If you want to test with them. Lower the fuzzball.token_sort_ratio to 40 instead of 70 and I guess you will have a couple of clusters. You will see the docs are not saved until the for loop has finished, this is my issue.

Comment: And the expected result from that is what? Input and Output. You've shown the input, now show the expected output.

Comment: @NeilLunn I just added the output. Please have a look.

Comment: @NeilLunn, do you have any idea why it does not save to the database after each interaction?